# How to save Image to sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite, imageview, android-sqlite

These codes can only capture and display image I took, and when I pressed save button, it only saves "Note title" onto my list View. And when I clicked "Note Title" it doesn't display the picture anymore. What should I add to save it and update it? Thanks.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
     data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap mphoto = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageviewid.setImageBitmap(mphoto);

    }
}

public void takeImageFromCamera(View view) {
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
}

private void saveNote(){
    fillNameIfEmpty();

    id = DbAccess.addNote(getBaseContext(), etName.getText().toString(), mFileName, DbContract.NoteEntry.TYPE_PHOTO, currentCat);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.toast_saved, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private void updateNote(){
    fillNameIfEmpty();

    DbAccess.updateNote(getBaseContext(), id, etName.getText().toString(), mFileName, currentCat);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.toast_updated, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `DbAccess` API doesn't know anything about an image in the note!

So I would extend your code to:

1. After picture is taken it saved in fail in application sandbox
2. Save filename of image assigned to note to database together with note

And don't forget to handle editing or deletion picture use cases!

Comment: Thanks! i would try this, can you give me an example to this?